# get qprocess output in slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qprocess

i have a problem with a small program (I am a beginner with c++ and qt).
On button press it starts a cli application with qprocess and the output should be displayed in a text field as soon as the cli app writes it to stdout or stderr.

i read that its a good idea to use signals and slots for this but it isnt working.

the compiler throws an error that in my slot getOutput() the "process" object isn't declared (C2065)

here is the code.

processgui.cpp:

```
#include "processgui.h"
#include "ui_processgui.h"
#include <QProcess>

processGui::processGui(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::processGui)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

processGui::~processGui()
{
    delete ui;
}

void processGui::on_startProcess_clicked() {

    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    QString program = "tracert";
    QString arguments = "";

    process->setReadChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

    process->start(program, QStringList() << arguments);

    process->waitForStarted();

    QObject::connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(getOutput()));

}

void processGui::getOutput() {

    QByteArray strdata = process->readAllStandardOutput();

    ui->textLog->append(strdata);

}
```

processgui.h :

```
#ifndef PROCESSGUI_H
#define PROCESSGUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class processGui;
}

class processGui : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit processGui(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~processGui();

private slots:
    void on_startProcess_clicked();

    void getOutput();

private:
    Ui::processGui *ui;
};

#endif // PROCESSGUI_H
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `QProcess *process` to your header and initialize it with `process = new QProcess(this)` in your constructor. That way you can access it in your slot.

Answer (score 1):

```
 QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
```

is declared in:

```
void processGui::on_startProcess_clicked()
```

it's a scope problem, process is a local variable not available in the whole class.

Comment: I fixed it with thugas advice. I thought that the connect made the process avaiable in the slot but you are right. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `QProcess` object inside a slot with `sender()`, like this:

```
void processGui::getOutput() 
{
    QProcess* process = qobject_cast<QProcess*>(sender());
    QByteArray strdata = process->readAllStandardOutput();    
}
```